# NSDate is null after being set

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code that is supposed to convert an `NSString` into an `NSdate`:

```
    NSString *dateStr = self.currentElement;
    NSLog(@"Raw date string: %@", dateStr);

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

That produces the following output:

```
Raw date string: 7/8/1806 12:00:00 AM
(null)
```

I am not sure why `*date` is still `null` right after I set it with `dateFromString`. What would cause this?

edit: after looking at the duplicate question, I changed my code to the following:

```
    NSString *dateStr = self.currentElement;
    NSLog(@"Raw date string: %@", dateStr);

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Which now produces the following output:

```
Raw date string: 7/8/1806 12:00:00 AM
1806-07-08 04:56:02 +0000
```

Why is the `NSdate` printing incorrectly even when it is using the exact same `NSDateFormatter` that I just used to make it?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the time at the end?  Or it doesn't like the single digit month or day?

Comment: BTW I found the duplicate SO question by typing the following into Google: nsdateformatter datefromstring

Comment: I can't believe that this is getting reopen votes.  He had a bad format, now he's upset that NSDate isn't formatted.  These are the two biggest errors made re NSDate.

Comment: (And the 3 minutes and 58 seconds offset is due to clock changes over the intervening 200 years.  Format the date and it would be "normal".)